# how to call a div to other page?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, load

I have a page that with a div and I want to show the div's content to another page inside a  div called location. The site is a wordpress site, here's what I've tried...

```
<div class="add_info" id="add_info">
    <p>
        <strong>Venue:</strong> Henry Jones Art Hotel
    </p>
    <p style=" text-indent: 3.5em;">
         5 Hunter St, Hobart TAS 7000
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Date: </strong>&nbsp; Monday 15 September
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Time: </strong>&nbsp; 3.00 – 5.00pm
    </p>
    <p style=" text-indent: 3.5em;">
        (2.30pm arrival for registration and refreshments)
    </p>
</div>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function()            
        $('#location').load('http://www.MYURL/smbforum/#add_info');
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ajax to make a call to the server page that returns html output(content of div that you want to display)..

Comment: can you give me a example please!

Comment: $.ajax({
      url: "test.html", 
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $("#results").append(html);
      }
});